# MvvmCross: How to bind to visibility of UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a view in iOS that needs to be displayed in two modes, one with a close button in the navigation header and one without a close button.  I added a bool in my viewmodel to handle this.  However, a UIBarButtonItem does not have a Hidden property to bind to this bool in my viewmodel.  Any suggestions on how to address this problem?  NOTE:  I do NOT need to change the visibility of this close button at runtime.  This is just an initial read-only setting I need before the view is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For static setup, you can just try inspecting a viewmodel property in your ViewDidLoad code.

For creating custom bindings, see https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/custom-bindings-in-mvvmcross

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but the visibility needed to change dynamically. I was able to mimic the visibility by disabling the button and setting the tint color to clear.

**Create a custom TargetBinding:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Hides a UIBarButtonItem by disabling and setting the TintColor to Clear
/// </summary>
public class UIBarButtonItemVisibilityTargetBinding : MvxConvertingTargetBinding
{
    protected UIBarButtonItem Button => base.Target as UIBarButtonItem;

    private readonly UIColor _tintColor;

    public UIBarButtonItemVisibilityTargetBinding(UIBarButtonItem button) : base(button)
    {
        this._tintColor = button.TintColor;

        if (button == null) {
            MvxBindingTrace.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Error, "Error - UIBarButtonItem is null in UIBarButtonItemVisibilityTargetBinding");
        }
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode => MvxBindingMode.OneWay;

    public override System.Type TargetType => typeof(bool);

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        var button = (UIBarButtonItem) target;
        var enabled = (bool) value;

        button.Enabled = enabled;
        button.TintColor = enabled ? _tintColor : UIColor.Clear;
    }
}
```

**Register your TargetBinding in your Setup File:**

```
    protected override void FillTargetFactories (MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.Construction.IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        base.FillTargetFactories (registry);

        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<UIBarButtonItem> ("Visibility", button => new UIBarButtonItemVisibilityTargetBinding (button));

    }
```

**Bind to the button in your view controller using the custom binding:**

```
set.Bind (btnBarItem).For("Visibility").To (vm => vm.ShowButton);
```